# Why is a simply connected 3-manifold a homotopy 3-sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I recently looked at the statement of the Poincare conjecture, and realized I didn't know why the fact that a 3-manifold is simply connected implies that it is homotopic to a 3-sphere. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a copy of a part of the note found [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/3Msurvey.pdf) (start at the bottom of the first page)

> In particular, if $M$ is a simply-connected closed 3 manifold, then $M$ has the same homology groups as the $3$ sphere $\mathbb S^3$. In fact $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb S^3$. For by the Hurewicz theorem $\pi_2(M) = H_2(M) = 0$ and $\pi_3(M) = H_3(M) = \mathbb Z$. A generator of $\pi_3(M)$ is represented by a map $\mathbb S^3\to M$ of degree one, inducing an isomorphism
>   on $H_3 = \pi_3$. This means we have a map $\mathbb S^3\to M$ of simply-connected simplicial complexes inducing isomorphisms on all homology groups, so by Whitehead’s theorem the map is a homotopy equivalence. Thus a simply-connected closed 3 manifold is a homotopy sphere.

Comment: You should also include the part where triangularisability and Poincaré duality are explained.